# How do I remove single-character whitespace between words, leaving multiple, contiguous, whitespace characters unchanged?

Tags: string-manipulation, text

In a string, I want to remove only the single-character whitespace between printing characters, leaving any multiple, contiguous, whitespace characters between printing characters unchanged?

What is needed is:

```
f["Is This OK,  huh?"]
```

> ```
> IsThisOk, huh?
> ```

`StringReplace` hasn't worked for me because I can't see how to restrict it to single-character whitespace.

```
StringReplace["Is This OK,  huh?", " " -> ""]
```

> IsThisOK,huh?

My string comes from `Import["url"]` and has a length in excess of 250,000 characters.

Answer (score 5):

```
StringReplace["Is This OK,  huh?", 
   {w : Repeated[WhitespaceCharacter, {2, Infinity}] :> w, WhitespaceCharacter -> ""}]
(* IsThisOK,  huh? *)
```

Note: If you also want to replace multiple contiguous white spaces with a single white space character, you can do

```
StringReplace["Is This OK,         huh?",
 {Repeated[WhitespaceCharacter, {2, Infinity}] -> " ",  WhitespaceCharacter -> ""}]
(* "IsThisOK, huh?" *)
```

Comment: Myyyyyyyy bad. I was making my own question here :P